# SonarQube, how specify list of files to analyse ?

Tags: sonarqube

Is there any way to pass list of files to SonarQube server, which i want to analyse using WebService API.

I dont want to analyse whole project. Because there are a lot of files and it will be not optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not do that using a web service. Please head to the ["Narrowing the focus" documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) that explains everything you want to know.

Mainly, you can use the `sonar.inclusions` property to list exactly the files you want to include in your analysis.